# knowing if a html button is clicked using cakephp in the view

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Here is a part of my cakephp view code:

```
</fieldset> 
   </form>
        <?php        
            $account = new Account();
            $account->insertPos();               
         ?>
   <button id="button" name="button" onClick="assign();" value="save"> Save Changes     </button> 
</body>
```

I need the php part to be executed only if the button is clicked, how can i check that the button is clicked inside my view and execute this php code...

Thank...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this in the same PHP request. By the time the user sees the button in order to click it, the page has finished rendering, the request is over, and PHP's job is complete.

You'll need to send another request to the server to make this happen, either via submitting a regular form, or via Ajax. Here's a simple non-Ajax solution (may require tweaking to fit with the rest of your code):

```
<div id="result"><?php
    if(isset($_POST['newaccount']))
    {
        $account = new Account();
        $account->insertPos();
    }
?></div>
<form id="newaccountform" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="button" name="newaccount" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you but when i refresh my page it resends the information and executes the function insertPos() without clicking on the sumbit button and this function inserts in the database so like this if a user refreshed the page everything will clash, so what can i do about this problem?...

Comment: You can do verification isPost in the controller before executing the function.  `if ($this->request->is('post')) { //execute your logic here    }`

Comment: if i want to give the function insertPos() some input paramaters returned from a javascript function to be insertPos(array,array1,array2) where array and array1 and array2 are 3 variables inside a javascript function in the same file....
can i do this or what?